# Setting pointer to a double array in for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, cuda, maya

I have an algorithm that I want to run that uses a potentially long double array. Because the array can be millions in length, I'm putting it on the GPU so I need to export the array from a CPP file to a CU file. However, Im prototyping it in CPP only for now because it doesnt work in either case.

In my CPU prototype I get errors when I try to set the members of the double array with my for loop. For example, any operation including cout will give error c2109:subscript requires array or pointer type in the CPP file

or if the same code is run from a CU file, error: expression  must have a pointer-to-object type

```
const int size = 100000;

double inputMeshPts_PROXY[size][4];
inputMeshPts.get(inputMeshPts_PROXY);

int lengthPts = inputMeshPts.length();

if (useCUDA == 1)
{
    double *inputMeshPts_CUDA = &inputMeshPts_PROXY[size][4];

    myArray(lengthPts, inputMeshPts_CUDA);
}

MStatus abjBlendShape::myArray(int length_CUDA, float weight_CUDA, double *inputMeshPts_CUDA)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length_CUDA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << inputMeshPts_CUDA[i][j] << endl;
            // inputMeshPts_CUDA[i][j] += (sculptedMeshPts_PROXY[i][j] - inputMeshPts_CUDA[i][j]); // WHAT I WANT, EVENTUALLY
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The array starts at `&inputMeshPts_PROXY[0][0]`.  What you have `&inputMeshPts_PROXY[size][4]` is waaay past the end, and actually illegal to even calculate the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

When you are writing:

```
double *inputMeshPts_CUDA = &inputMeshPts_PROXY[size][4];
```

The variable inputMeshPts_CUDA is a pure pointer. You cannot use 2-dimensional indexing  [][] as before. The right way to access it is now to linearize the indexes:

```
inputMeshPts_CUDA[i*4+j]
```

Alternatively you could declare "correctly" your pointer:

```
double (*inputMeshPts_CUDA)[4] = inputMeshPts_PROXY;
```

which allows you to use the 2-dimensional indexing again.

Comment: That last line is a wild pointer (yes, I know the question did it wrong too)

Answer (score 2):

```
MStatus abjBlendShape::myArray(int length_CUDA, float weight_CUDA, double *inputMeshPts_CUDA)
{
```

`inputMeshPts_CUDA` is just a pointer, the compiler has lost all the dimension information.  It needs that dimension information for `inputMeshPts_CUDA[i][j]`, which gets converted to an access to address (byte arithmetic, not C++ pointer arithmetic)

```
inputMeshPts_CUDA + i * sizeof (double) * num_colums + j * sizeof (double)
```

You can either provide the missing information yourself and do the arithmetic like Angew suggests, or have the compiler pass the dimension information through:

```
template<size_t M, size_t N>
MStatus abjBlendShape::myArray(int length_CUDA, float weight_CUDA, double (&inputMeshPts_CUDA)[M][N])
```

Of course, this only works when the size is known at compile-time.

Comment: Another disadvantage of the template-based solution is that the template is reinstantiated for different array sizes.

Comment: Cuda supports "VLA" like declaration as far as I remember:

void func(int size, int (*ptr)[size])

Answer (score 0):

`inputMeshPts_CUDA` is a pointer to `double` - that is, it can represent a 1D array. You're accessing it as a 2D array: `inputMeshPts_CUDA[i][j]`. That doesn't make sense - you're effectively applying `[j]` to the `double` object storead at `inputMeshPts_CUDA[i]`.

I believe you were looking for `inputMeshPts_CUDA[i * 4 + j]` - you have to compute the 2D addressing yourself.

Comment: 2-D arrays are stored as contiguous memory, and the address of one is a `double*` (single indirection).  But no, pointer arithmetic doesn't work.

Comment: It is not i * 3 + j but i * 4 + j.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, that's what I meant - you can't use 2D-array indexing on a `double*`.

Comment: @Joky Right, I guess. I was confused by the inner loop's limit.